# \settowidth in preamble wrong with fontspec+lualatex w/ MWE

Tags: spacing, luatex, fontspec, preamble

I am getting some strange behaviour using luaLaTeX and a rather simple command definition. I am using TeXLive 2012, Linux x86_64.

When `\settowidth` is used in the preamble to compute the width of some characters in the following example, the width is terribly underestimated, and when that width is used to negatively indent some text, it does not line up.

If the `\settowidth` operating is moved inside the document environment, the calculation is just fine.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage{fontspec}

\newdimen\arrowwidth
\settowidth{\arrowwidth}{$\rightarrow$\ }
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\noindent\hskip-\arrowwidth{$\rightarrow$\ }{#1}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
%\settowidth{\arrowwidth}{$\rightarrow$\ }
\note{HELLO WORLD!}

\lipsum[2-2]

\end{document}
```

If you uncomment the line above the `\note{HELLO WORLD}`, everything works as expected.

Changing the `12pt` option also changes the issue somewhat drastically.

The `→` character isn't the problem. You can substitute roman text for the right arrow and it will still give problems.

Does anyone have any idea what causes this? Can anyone else reproduce it?

Comment: Before using `\settowidth` in the preamble set issue the command `\rmfamily`.  This forces your font choices to take effect at that point rather than being delayed to the \begin{document} command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For technical reasons, `fontspec` delays some font settings after the preamble has been completely read in. In particular, the font size is still 10pt when you do the `\settowidth` command. You can solve the issue by forcing `\normalsize` in the command:

```
\settowidth{\arrowwidth}{\normalsize$\rightarrow$\ }
```

But there's a slicker way to define your `\note` command:

```
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\noindent\makebox[0pt][r]{$\rightarrow$\ }#1}
```

that doesn't require any measuring.

Comment: Thanks! That zero-width box trick is quite brilliant. I could have sworn I tried the `\normalsize`, but it didn't work. Perhaps I'm mistaken.

Comment: I'm wondering if this isn't a bug. fontspec doesn't really delay the size setting but changes it: before loading fontspec `\f@size` is 12pt and afterwards it is 10pt.

Comment: @Timtro Ulrike (she's a Mrs, by the way) *is* right. I remember that this has been discussed somewhere.